# Desplegar REST API (Node & Typescript Angular Mysql CRUD) v2

Tags: mysql, nodejs, angular, typescript, express

video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxYB79ANJM8&t=6917s ....
he hecho todo lo del video, en local me funciona al 100%, el problema es cuando lo subo a un hosting, OK el video dice q la carpeta (server/build) es la que se tiene que subir y en la carpeta de (client) por medio del comando "ng build --prod" subo la carpeta que genera (dist). ok asi lo tengo subido ya.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]. pero antes en el video dice que en esta parte [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] hay que cambiar lo de lo localhost, por el dominio. y lo he cambiado y ya esta subido.
pero el error que me muestra en el navegador el este:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] sera que tengo q subir lo del servidor y cliente en diferentes lugares? porpue ahi lo he subido a uno solo todo como lo ven la primera imagen. o el hosting no permite eso? estoy usando mysql...

me ha empezado a salir este error ahora, lo de CORS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu valor de `API_URI` en localhost apunta a una ruta `api` en cambio la que escribes con el host apunta una ruta raíz. Verifica eso, porque en todo caso debería ser `http://pruebasangular.bytehost22.com/api`

Comment: @MauricioContreras ahorita lo he intentado pero **{headers: t, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://pruebasangular.byethost22.com/api/games", ok: false,** sigue con lo mismo :/

Comment: No solo hay que subir los archivos. tu hosting tiene que levantar esos archivos y servilos de alguna forma. Tu hosting, hace eso? o sea, levanta un servidor que permita conexiones rest a tu api?

Comment: Pues como va creo que no, y que hosting me recomiendas? @gbianchi

Comment: Googlea sobre las tecnologias que estas usando, y hay montones de sitios pagos y no pagos para elegir. En localhost justamente funciona, porque tenes un servidor de algun tipo que sirve los archivos

Comment: Claro, @gbianchi tiene razón. Asumí que tu hosting estaba levantando el servidor de la API. Verifica que puedes hacerlo, no conozco el hosting que usas. Puedes probar [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com), pero tal vez requieras ajustar algunas cosas para hacer el deploy. Suerte y saludos.

Comment: @MauricioContreras es el poder de ver a travez de las preguntas ;)

Answer (score 1):

eh visto a ese youtuber antes, en especifico eh visto ese video, creo que uno de tus problemas es que necesitas levantar el servidor que estas usando de backend, mira, en ese mismo canal hay un video de como subir una aplicacion de nodejs, deberias verlo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yKWQKO4XU5I lo unico que tendrias que hacer seria ignorar la parte que habla sobre mongodb y utilizar el servicio de mysql de tu hosting actual.

ademas para el problema del CORS, en el backend especifica de donde recibiras las peticiones.

ejemplo: probablemente tengas esta linea en tu index.ts

```
this.app.use(cors());
```

si tus peticiones vienen de localhost:4200 (o de algun otro dominio) deberias agregarlo junto con credentials: true

```
this.app.use(cors({
origin: ['http://localhost:4200', 'http://127.0.0.1:4200'],
credentials: true
}))
```

Comment: Mmm entonces subo la carpeta "Server" o "Client" ?? como las trabaja por ceparado